# Spring security for REST and Angular 2.0

Tags: rest, spring-security, angular

Working on a Login application. Separated the front end with Angular2 and accessing backend using REST implemented with Spring. Initially implemented Login app with spring security but no angular 2 just with plain jsp.

Now I want to achieve the same with REST. Need some inputs on this.

1. Angular 2 front end
2. Spring REST API's for login, register, logout,...
3. Spring security with OAuth.

Later I wanted to extend the same with OpenId(Google and Facebook)

Comment: are you able to get it work ?

Comment: While this would make a great tutorial I fear it is far too broad for a SO question.

Comment: REST isn't a JSON based Web-API but an architectural style used to decouple clients from servers by utilizing the semantics of operations provided by a backing transport protocol in order to exchange state of a resource in accordande to a negotiated media-type representation. The coupling therefore shifts between client and server to a intermediary media-type. So, why do you even bother on trying to REST-ify your login when probably only your frontend will talk to it anyway?

Answer (score 0):

See this repo for an example of Rest API's, login, Spring, Spring Security, JWT and Angular 2.

However there is not OAuth example.

https://github.com/RedFroggy/angular-spring-hmac/tree/master

Comment: This is a very good example, it would be even better if the author switched to Angular 2.1.0 final

Comment: I'm getting page not found from the above link.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example, Also you will found **OAuth2** Implementation here with different examples.

[OAUTH2_SPRING_BOOT2_MYSQL](https://github.com/imrangthub/OAUTH2_SPRING_BOOT2_MYSQL) and **Spring Security** With **Angular** Client